# Git no longer waits on Notepad++ to finish with a file before continuing

Tags: git, notepad++, git-bash

On my Windows 10 machine, my configured editor for git-bash to open is Notepad++.  If notepad++ is open when I run any git command (from git-bash on windows) that requires opening an editor, git opens the temporary file in the existing instance of Notepad++, but git doesn't wait.  It used to, I think.  What happened?  The result is that it proceeds with whatever default content is in the file it opened.  In the case of a `git rebase -i <commit-spec>`, since the content specifying which commits to squash was never altered, no harm is done.  In the case of a `git commit`, since no comment gets to be entered, the commit gets cancelled.  If you try to edit the file and save it anyway, you get a message that it can't be saved.  (This is because git has already deleted the file after reading back the default content and processing it.)  Is there a configuration setting to tell git to use a new instance of Notepad++?

Comment: sounds like a notepadd++ problem. Git will wait for the process it called to relinquish control (normally, when it ends)... if the process is detaching, there's nothing git can do to help it.

Comment: The same happens to me with kate _if there are more instances of kate running_. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: So I need some way to tell Notepad++ to start a new instance, and that might be a command-line parameter to insert into my gitconfig.  It's time to do more searching in the Notepad++ docs, unless anyone else knows this off the top of their head.

Comment: I think I found the Notepad++ command-line option:
-multiInst: Launch another Notepad++ instance, so user can have several Notepad++ simultaneously.  I'm trying this in .gitconfig
[core]
 editor = 'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe -multiInst '

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I found that works:

Edit your Global .gitconfig file, in the [core] section, make sure editor keyword looks like this:

`editor = 'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin`

The point here is we want a new instance (-multiInst), and since we don't want to be tempted to open other stuff in this Notepad++ instance, we also suppress showing a tab bar (-notabbar), prevent it from opening any files from a previous session (-noSession), and don't bother loading plug-ins (-noPlugin).

Notice too, that it appears everything after the = will be used, so the quotes go around the exe only and do not include the options.  You're trying to tell the shell what the path is to your exe, and since there's a space in it, you need the quotes (or apostrophes).

Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: "The point here is we want a new instance (-multiInst), "

What if I don't? I want one instance

Answer (score 1):

Use this command for **Windows**

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -nosession -notabbar"
```