Git hangs on waiting for editor to close after closing notepad++
I want to amend the committed message for the latest commit (already push but no one pull it yet), I open command prompt and type
git commit --amend

then it automatically pop up the notepad++, then I modify the committed message, save and then close the notepad++ by clicking the top right X button, but then the message

Hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...

keep showing and no any response if I type anything on the command prompt.
What should I do now?

The message is inaccurate. Closing the file is not sufficient (there is no way for a process to notice that it was closed). You must close the editor.

yes, need close the editor, no just close the file, thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63529756/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/64725213/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git%20notepad%2b%2b

It seems that Git is still waiting for the Notepad++'s process to end. If you're on Windows, open the task manager, select the Details tab, and make sure to terminate Notepad++'s process to resume the execution in Git.
